# Visual Studio 2015 preventing an application from opening the console

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I am making an application using Windows.Form in Visual Studio 2015, but I have a console popping up whenever I run the program. This is great for debugging, but how do I stop this from happening when I finish my program? I have looked at some similar questions, but they are all for different versions of Visual Studio.

Comment: Did you create a console project and then add windows forms to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go to `Project -> (Project Name) Properties... -> Application Tab` and change the `Output type` from `Console Application` to `Windows Application`.